# Example for adding images to a linked list in java

Tags: java, image, linked-list

I have been trying to add images to a linked list.
How can I add images to a linked list in java after the declaration. Can anyone please help me with a sample code for doing that?

I have tried adding the images in a file object but I do not understand how to add that to a linked list.

```
File f = new File(getClass().getResource(path).getFile());

LinkedList = new LinkedList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LinkedList<>` type is a template type, which is shown by the fact that its definition has those weird angle brackets `<>`. This means that it will work for any type. The way that works is you declare your `LinkedList<>` something like this

```
LinkedList<File> files = new LinkedList<>();
```

Now, `files` will store a list of `File` types.

EDIT: You cannot store `Image` types because your variables that you want to store are not of type `Image`. They are of type `File`.

EDIT: You can store files in this list with the code

```
files.add(file);
```

where `file` is the file you want to store. For more information on `LinkedList<>`, check out https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html

Comment: Can you give me an example on how I can add elements to such a list?

Answer (score 1):

```
    LinkedList<File> a = new LinkedList<>();
    File f = new File(getClass().getResource(path).getFile());
    a.add(f);
```

You define `LinkedList` of type `File`, and add your file object to the list by using the `add` method.